# Using global variable for SQL select statment - VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am using the following code to fill a DataGridView on a form called DaisyServicesForm

```vb
'//Fill Table
GlobalVar.dataadapter2.Fill(GlobalVar.ds2, "Missing")
DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView3.AutoGenerateColumns = False
DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView3.DataSource = GlobalVar.ds2.Tables("Missing")
```

Because it loads the data to another form I have configured my variables using a Public Class so that they are available.

```vb
Public Class GlobalVar

Public Shared Filename2 As String

'//build table on left for missing items
Public Shared ds2 As DataSet = New DataSet()
Public Shared connStr2 As String = "server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyServices; integrated security=yes"
Public Shared sql2 As String = "SELECT i.[ID],i.[Site],i.[CLI],i.[CustomerName],i.[FromDate],i.[ToDate],i.[Quantity],i.[UnitCost],i.[TotalCost],i.[Description],i.[filenameonly],i.billingmonth as [CurrentBillingMonth], i.bill From [DaisyServices].[dbo].[DaisyServicesIndigo] i LEFT JOIN [DaisyServices].[dbo].[" & GlobalVar.Filename2 & "] s on i.[SITE]=s.[SITE] AND i.[CLI]=s.[CLI] AND i.[Quantity]=s.[Quantity] AND i.[UnitCost]=s.[UnitCost] AND i.[TotalCost]=s.[TotalCost] AND i.[Description]=s.[Description] WHERE s.[CLI] is NULL"
Public Shared conn2 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(GlobalVar.connStr2)
Public Shared comm2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(GlobalVar.sql2, GlobalVar.conn2)
Public Shared dataadapter2 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(GlobalVar.comm2)

End Class
```

The trouble is when I run the code, using a click button event it fails with the following error message.

"An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name."

It would appear the Filename variable is not being passed correctly.

I have tested the variable exists by way of a MsgBox and when I hard code the dynamic table name it works ok.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, global connection string names and static query strings are probably OK (app.config?), but making the other objects static will quickly trip up if you have more than one thread?

Comment: Can we have to code where you pass the value to Filename2 please?

Comment: I grab it from a combobox selection. GlobalVar.Filename2 = ComboBox1.Text

Comment: GlobalVar is not a variable, but a user defined type.  Define your variable : Dim GV as new GlobalVar, then call GV.Filename2 = ComboBox1.Text and GV.dataadapter2.Fill(GlobalVar.ds2, "Missing")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shared` variables are created as soon as the program starts. You have

```
Public Shared comm2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(GlobalVar.sql2, GlobalVar.conn2)
```

wich creates the command with sql2 when `FileName2` isn't initialized yet.

You could solve this creating a method in your public class to initialize your connections, commands, and DataAdapters...

```
Public Class GlobalVar

    Public Shared Filename2 As String

    ''build table on left for missing items
    Public Shared ds2 As DataSet
    Public Shared connStr2 As String
    Public Shared sql2 As String
    Public Shared conn2 As SqlConnection
    Public Shared comm2 As SqlCommand
    Public Shared dataadapter2 As SqlDataAdapter

    Public Shared Sub InitializeConnection()
        ''Call this after you fill Filename2
        ds2 = New DataSet()
        connStr2 = "server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyServices; integrated security=yes"
        sql2 = "SELECT i.[ID],i.[Site],i.[CLI],i.[CustomerName],i.[FromDate],i.[ToDate],i.[Quantity],i.[UnitCost],i.[TotalCost],i.[Description],i.[filenameonly],i.billingmonth as [CurrentBillingMonth], i.bill From [DaisyServices].[dbo].[DaisyServicesIndigo] i LEFT JOIN [DaisyServices].[dbo].[" & GlobalVar.Filename2 & "] s on i.[SITE]=s.[SITE] AND i.[CLI]=s.[CLI] AND i.[Quantity]=s.[Quantity] AND i.[UnitCost]=s.[UnitCost] AND i.[TotalCost]=s.[TotalCost] AND i.    [Description]=s.[Description] WHERE s.[CLI] is NULL"
        conn2 = New SqlConnection(GlobalVar.connStr2)
        comm2 = New SqlCommand(GlobalVar.sql2, GlobalVar.conn2)
        dataadapter2 = New SqlDataAdapter(GlobalVar.comm2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

...**BUT** I really encourage you to rethink your design. For example, you can create a function in your public class that creates all the connections and adapters you need for that function, open and close those connections and return the DataAdapter you need. Something like:

```
Public Class GlobalVar
    ''Do not declare anything here...

    Public Shared Function FillData(ByVal Filename2 as string) as DataSet
        ''...instead put inside this function your connections, data adapters, sql sentences,
        ''and use them to fill and return the dataset with the data you need
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sql2` variable will be initialized the first time the `GlobalVar` class is referenced, using the then-current value of `Filename2`, which will be `Nothing`.  Future changes to `Filename2` will have no impact on the value of `sql2`.

As a simple example, see the following code (paste into LINQPad to test):

```vb
Sub Main
    Console.WriteLine("String1:{0}", Test.String1)
    Console.WriteLine("String2:{0}", Test.String2)
    Test.String1 = "Goodbye"
    Console.WriteLine("String1:{0}", Test.String1)
    Console.WriteLine("String2:{0}", Test.String2)
End Sub

' Define other methods and classes here
Public Class Test
    Public Shared String1 As String = "Hello"
    Public Shared String2 As String = Test.String1 & " World"
End Class
```

This outputs the following:

```
String1:Hello
String2:Hello World
String1:Goodbye
String2:Hello World
```